# Email validation failed when using omniauth+twitter+devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth

I'm using the code from this [Railcast episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/235-devise-and-omniauth-revised), the code is in [Github here](https://github.com/railscasts/235-devise-and-omniauth-revised/tree/master/blog-after).

Unfortunately, I get the error: `The change you wanted was rejected.` (Ironically, I have implemented this several times and it has never happened to me before)

In Heroku's log, I get:

```
    2013-07-13T09:06:49.096663+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 422 Unprocessable Entityin 83ms
    2013-07-13T09:06:49.099178+00:00 app[web.1]:
    2013-07-13T09:06:49.099178+00:00 app[web.1]: ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid (Validation failed: Email can't be blank):
   2013-07-13T09:06:49.099178+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/models/user.rb:14:in `from_omniauth'
    2013-07-13T09:06:49.099178+00:00 app[web.1]:
    2013-07-13T09:06:49.099178+00:00 app[web.1]:
    2013-07-13T09:06:49.099178+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/models/user.rb:20:in `block in from_omniauth'
   2013-07-13T09:06:49.099178+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb:3:in `all'
```

I believe that it is the email validation failure made the erro. Since in my `from_omniauth` method, i do not retrieve the email.

```
  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first_or_create do |user|
      user.provider = auth.provider
      user.uid = auth.uid
      user.name = auth.info.nickname
      user.image = auth.info.image
      user.save!
    end
  end
```

Does the validation failure prevents the `user.save!`? Can I not use it later on in omniauth_callbacks?

Comment: Generated Devise migration adds not null and unique on email column, maybe that's the case?

Comment: Yes, I have that. So this would prevent the `.save?`

Comment: But in one of my olrder repos. I also got this `t.string :email,  :null => false, :default => ""` It worked at that time.

Comment: Yes, I think it would. I also remember that this problem never occured to me before last project so I think it may be a regression in Devise.

Comment: LOl, you got the same problem. So how can I deal with it?

Comment: Maybe we could specify an eariler version in `gemfile`?

Comment: I changed the migration and reset my db (project in works with no real data) but you can as well add a migration like in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figure it out
use `where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first_or_initialize do |user|` 
to replace`where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first_or_create do |user|`
and remove `save!` in the block

Answer (score 1):

I suggest adding a migration like this

```
remove_index :users, :email
change_column :users, :email, default: nil, allow_null: true
```

If you wish to keep an index on email for fast lookups add also

```
add_index :users, :email # this index will be simple btree in postgres, not uniq
```

add this method on your user model

```
def email_required?
  provider.blank?
end
```

But if you still want to get email address from user you'd need to add a second signup step to do so.

Comment: There's unique index only on email. You can add regular index if you wish, updating answer

Comment: but how would this affect people who want to sign up to the site? So we need to add a email validate statement in User model?

Comment: Yes you would need to validate email for users who sign up in regular way (with email and password)

Comment: well.. I tried add the validation. It still reports `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid (Validation failed: Email can't be blank, Email can't be blank)` `def email_required?
  super && provider.blank?` is working, but we dont get the email anymore......